# Should href lang links be deep or point to the home page?

Tags: seo, internationalization, language, hreflang

I have a website `http://www.example.com/convert.html` and would like to have multilanguage versions of the website; for example German (`http://www.example.com/de/konvertieren.html`) and French (`http://www.example.com/fr/convertir.html`).

I "manually" translated all the pages including the Menu items, Footer, Header etc into the respective languages. So I basically now have 3 versions of my website with whole content in a different language.
In every page of all 3 websites I have included

```
<link rel="x-default" href="http://example.com/en" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/de" hreflang="de" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/fr" hreflang="fr" />
```

Is that the correct way to do it or should it be a link to the page like

```
<link rel="x-default" href="http://example.com/en/convert.html" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/de/konvertieren.html" hreflang="de" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/fr/convertir.html" hreflang="fr" />
```

Comment: The second way is correct. See [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077) from Google:  `rel="alternate" hreflang="x" is used as a page level, not a site level, and you need to mark up each set of pages, including the home page, as appropriate`

Comment: if the hlang tag is used but the text is not exactly same as the english version (adjusted to french audience) would that be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The site that I manage has an english version as our main site and then an additional canadian site. Here's the hreflang tags that I have implemented:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/test" />
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="http://m.example.com/test" >
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-ca" href="http://www.example.ca/test" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/test" />
```